# How to change State of App component in react

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import './App.css';

import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component';
import ShopPage from './pages/shop/shop.component';
import SignInAndSignUpPage from './pages/sign-in-and-sign-up/sign-in-and-sign-up.component';
import Header from './components/header/header.component';
import { setCurrentUser } from './redux/user/user.actions';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    };
  }

  handleLoggedIn = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentUser:"user"
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/shop' component={ShopPage} />
          <Route path='/signin'   render={() => (
            <SignInAndSignUpPage handleLoggedIn={this.handleLoggedIn} />
          )} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;





import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { auth } from '../../firebase/firebase.utils';

import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/crown.svg';

import './header.styles.scss';

const Header = ({ currentUser }) => (
  <div className='header'>
    <Link className='logo-container' to='/'>
      <Logo className='logo' />
    </Link>
    <div className='options'>
      <Link className='option' to='/shop'>
        SHOP
      </Link>
      <Link className='option' to='/shop'>
        CONTACT
      </Link>
      {currentUser ? (
        <div className='option' onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
          SIGN OUT
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Link className='option' to='/signin'>
          SIGN IN
        </Link>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

sharing my Header component also
as per the comment. Please have a  look

Here i am storing user in state then sending the state in to Header component 
BUt always i am getting null data

the handleLoggedIn function is calling when user is signin then i amcalling it from child component.

Please have  a look where i am doing wrong.

Comment: What does your Header component look like and how do you know its getting null data?

Comment: I am doing alert there.

Comment: It is coming null

Comment: Gotcha. Can you please show us the code for your Header component? I'm sure we can resolve it. Based on the code you have provided so far, it doesnt look like anything is wrong with this file. So likely has to do with either the Header or Signup components.

Comment: Shared And edited questuion

Comment: Ok so we’re kind of forced to take your word for it that the `handleLoggedIn` functions is being called, and you are still getting `null` data. You are also confusing things a lot by mapping state to props using the exact same key name there as you are passing in as an own prop. You really should not have both, and should choose one. If you could clean that up, and perhaps strip out some complexity your React Router is introducing, also perhaps putting this in a code sandbox, I bet you’d find more help